# Can't Establish Connection to Sql Server Using Azure Active Directory Credentials Without password

Tags: sql-server, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, ado.net

I need to connect to Sql Server by the current logged-in user email,
I do not want to specify user Id and password in my connection string. I have tried a solution found here https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-sql-server-managed-identity/
My Code is

```
static public DataTable GetDataTable(string Query, string ServerName, string DatabaseName)
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection($"Server={ServerName};Database={DatabaseName}");
            var azureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
            azureCredentialOptions.SharedTokenCacheUsername = "testUser@abc.com";
            var defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(azureCredentialOptions);
            var token = defaultCredential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
            conn.AccessToken = token.Token;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt == null)
                dt = new DataTable();
            return dt;
        }
```

But i am facing this exception when its try to connect to sql server

> SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
> The server is not currently configured to accept this token.

Comment: Could you please try to use Managed identity as mentioned in this MS DOC:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-managed-identity-authentication .

Comment: Side point: you must dispose your connection and adapter with `using`

Comment: You are setting the `SharedTokenCacheUsername`, that is not right, and glaringly insecure - and as you can see that is **not** how it is done in the article you quoted.